# slideUp and slideDown doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery

Following is the code for hiding and showing a submenu, this codes works fine in firefox, but doesnt work in IE.

```
function showAccountMenu(){
    $('#menu li').hover(function (){
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(100);
    },
    function (){
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
    }
);
```

The css for the follwing code is

```
#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:-107px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Can anyone please tell whats wrong with this code.

Comment: can you post your code by making fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/75NKZ/ is the fiddle link.........thanks

Comment: IE 6 and below do not support `:hover` on anything except `<a>` elements, and IE7 and 8 have odd behavior for other elements.

Comment: In my css I just did one change by removing the position:absolute and the menu works but you cant see the text written........did anyone had the same problem.............

Comment: Why the use of this, why not just `$('ul').slideDown(100);`

Comment: I was using slideup and slidedown but they both also gave the same problem...........

Comment: strange.. your fiddle is working fine in IE8 and 9.In which version you are trying?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with CSS..............

Comment: the solution is nothing to do with html and jquery code. The only changes to be done is to remove the position absolute and use font if you are missing it. 
Thanks friends for all your support.